# Python Custom sort files read from directory

Tags: python, sorting, python-os

I have a directory with the following structure :

```
Main directory:
|--2001
   |--200101
      |--feed_013_01.zip
      |--feed_restr_013_01.zip
      |--feed_013_04.zip
      |--feed_restr_013_04.zip
      ...
      |--feed_013_30.zip
      |--feed_restr_013_30.zip
...
|--2021
   |--202101
      |--feed_013_01.zip
      |--feed_restr_013_01.zip
      |--feed_013_04.zip
      |--feed_restr_013_04.zip
      ...
      |--feed_013_30.zip
      |--feed_restr_013_30.zip
```

I need to read and sort the zip files in order:

```
feed_restr_013_30.zip, feed_013_30.zip.....feed_restr_013_01.zip, feed_013_01.zip
```

I am currently doing something like this :

```
def atoi(text):
    return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text

def natural_keys(text):
    return [atoi(c) for c in re.split(r'(\d+)', text)]

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    subdirs.sort(key=natural_keys)
    subdirs.reverse()
    files.sort(key=natural_keys)
    files.reverse()
```

It takes all the "restr" files first and I am getting the list as :

```
feed_restr_013_30.zip,feed_restr_013_01.zip.....feed_013_30.zip, feed_013_01.zip
```

**UPDATE**

I was able to solve this using buran's and SCKU's answer coupled with my existing logic

```
def atoi(text):
    return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text

def parse(fname):
    try:
        prefix, *middle, n1, n2 = fname.split('_')
    except:
        prefix, *middle, n1 = fname.split('_')
        n2 = ''
    return (prefix, n1, [atoi(c) for c in re.split(r'(\d+)',n2)], ''.join(middle))

def get_Files(self, directory, source, keywords):
    file_paths = []
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            file_name = os.path.join(path, file)
            file_paths.append(file_name)
    return file_paths

files = get_Files(directory, source, keywords)
files.sort(key=parse, reverse=True)
```

Comment: can you also post code where you finally print the sorted files?

Comment: You have duplicated files in two folders, how these should be managed?

Comment: @crayxt The folders should be sorted in reverse order first, then the files. I am traversing folder by folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
files = ['feed_013_01.zip', 'feed_restr_013_01.zip',
        'feed_013_04.zip', 'feed_restr_013_04.zip', 
        'feed_013_30.zip', 'feed_restr_013_30.zip']

def parse(fname):
    prefix, *middle, n1, n2 = fname.split('_')
    return (prefix, int(n1), int(n2), ''.join(middle))

files.sort(key=parse, reverse=True)
print(files)
```

output

```
['feed_restr_013_30.zip', 'feed_013_30.zip', 'feed_restr_013_04.zip', 'feed_013_04.zip',
 'feed_restr_013_01.zip', 'feed_013_01.zip']
```

Comment: This works for the "restr" files. But the sorting for numbers is not correct. I get the list as `['feed_restr_013_9.zip', 'feed_013_9.zip', 'feed_restr_013_8.zip', 'feed_013_8.zip', 'feed_restr_013_7.zip', 'feed_013_7.zip', 'feed_restr_013_2.zip', 'feed_013_2.zip', 'feed_restr_013_19.zip', 'feed_013_19.zip', 'feed_restr_013_18.zip', 'feed_013_18.zip', 'feed_restr_013_17.zip', 'feed_013_17.zip']` The files should be sorted numerically as well.

Comment: convert `n1` and `n2` to `int` in the return statement. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your directories structured very well and not too big, I recommand to get all files path and sort them at once:

```
#get all file with path
all_files_path = []
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for f in files:
        all_files_path.append(os.path.join(path, f))

# define custom sort key function
def which_items_you_want_to_compare(fpath):
    #from buran's answer for sorting the part of file name
    def parse(fname):
        prefix, *middle, n1, n2 = fname.split('_')
        return (prefix, n1, n2, ''.join(middle))

    fpath_split = fpath.split(os.path.sep)
    fn = fpath_split[-1] # file name 'feed_restr_013_01.zip'
    sort_key_fn = parse(fn) # from buran's answer
    d_ym = fpath_split[-2] # dir '202101'
    d_y = fpath_split[-3] # dir '2021'
    
    #compare with year first, then month (last two words in d_ym), then file name sort from buran's answer
    return (int(d_y), int(d_ym[4:])) + sort_key_fn 


sorted_res = sorted(all_files_path, key=which_items_you_want_to_compare, reverse=True)
```

If you don't want to sort year by reverse, you can use `-int(d_y)` etc. in key function to reverse it back.